# installing grails in linux

Tags: linux, grails

I am new to using Linux. I installed grails by setting env variable GRAILS_HOME and added ot to PATH variable. I also exported both and when I typed in grails command.. It worked fine. When I closed that terminal session and opened a another new session, all the env variables that I had set up has all gone.

I was wondering how to have them available for all sessions.

Any help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: you need to add `GRAILS_HOME/bin` to the `PATH` (rather than `GRAILS_HOME`)

Comment: check the path is set or not with command "printenv"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Edit the .bashrc file of the user launching Grails.

Add the same lines as your commands:

```
GRAILS_HOME=/home/of/grails

export GRAILS_HOME

PATH=$PATH:$GRAILS_HOME/bin
```

Answer (score 4):

you need to add `$GRAILS_HOME/bin` to the `PATH` (rather than `$GRAILS_HOME`)

### Update

The best way to install Grails on Linux/Mac is to use [GVM](http://gvmtool.net/).

> GVM is a tool for managing parallel Versions of multiple Software Development Kits on most Unix based systems. It provides a convenient command line interface for installing, switching, removing and listing Candidates.

In addition to Grails, you can also use GVM to manage your installation of

- Groovy
- Griffon
- Gradle
- vert.x

Comment: Great that you mentioned GVM! Intellij asks me for `GRAILS_ROOT`. Is that the same as `GRAILS_HOME`?

Comment: I don't know what `GRAILS_ROOT` is. I also use IntelliJ but have never been asked to set this variable.

Answer (score 3):

If you have an Ubuntu (or equal) installation. You could add a repository to it. It should do all the stuff for you:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:groovy-dev/grails
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grails
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to set them under ~/.bashrc file and then type `source ~/.bashrc` in your terminal so you don't have to close and re-open it again.

Answer (score 0):

In `/etc/profile.d/` create a script name `grails.sh`:

```
export GRAILS_HOME=/opt/grails

export PATH=$GRAILS_HOME/bin:$PATH
```

Change `/opt/grails` to where you unzipped grails.

This will make it available for all users.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on ubuntu define the GRAILS_HOME variable with its installation path  in /etc/environment and edit the system path variable as shown in second line

GRAILS_HOME=/opt/grails
PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/opt/grails2/bin:"

Answer (score 0):

**Groovy Grails Installation:**

Before starting up install JAVA on linux system

Check java version using command

```
$> java -version
```

Install grails on Linux using [Installing-a-grails-development-environment-on-linux](http://www.grailsexample.net/installing-a-grails-development-environment-on-linux/)

Before installing grails will need to install GVM (Grails version manager) from [GVM Tool Installation](http://gvmtool.net/)

After installation of GVM from the above link, we will be able to run Grails sample application. Check it out with command

```
$> grails -version
```

Check Environment variable is set or not for Java as well as Grails with command

```
$> printenv
```

Create demo application and run the server for Grails using:

```
$> grails create-app demo
```

Go to path

```
$> cd demo/
```

Run the server

```
$> grails run-app
```

Run the server on specific port 9090

```
$> grails run-app -Dserver.port=9090
```

**Tools and running environment set up for Groovy Grails:**

Install **GGTS (Groovy Grails Tool Suit)** using [GGTS with Eclipse IDE and tool](http://spring.io/tools/ggts/all)

Select Eclipse package on linux from the above link:

**YouTube Video Tutorial:**

All Grails documentation video tutorials for the installations and running sample application is present here [YouTube Channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=HuDVCiyBsVY)