# Grails - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: _PluginDependencies_groovy$_run_closure1

Tags: grails

I am just setting up Grails on my pc and following the reference
http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/gettingStarted.html#creatingAnApplication

The below command, gives me error. Please help.

```
C:\Users\jjayarman>grails create-app helloworld --stacktrace
| Environment set to development....
| Error Error executing script CreateApp: _PluginDependencies_groovy$_run_closure1 (NOTE: Stack trace has been filtered. Use --verbose to see entire t
            race.)
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: _PluginDependencies_groovy$_run_closure1
at _PluginDependencies_groovy.run(_PluginDependencies_groovy:43)
at _PluginDependencies_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
at _GrailsArgParsing_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets.leftShift(IncludeTargets.groovy:59)
at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets$leftShift.call(Unknown Source)
at _GrailsInit_groovy.run(_GrailsInit_groovy:35)
at _GrailsInit_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
at _GrailsCompile_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets.leftShift(IncludeTargets.groovy:59)
at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets$leftShift.call(Unknown Source)
at _GrailsCompile_groovy.run(_GrailsCompile_groovy:28)
at _GrailsCompile_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
at _GrailsPackage_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets.leftShift(IncludeTargets.groovy:59)
at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets$leftShift.call(Unknown Source)
at _GrailsPackage_groovy.run(_GrailsPackage_groovy:28)
at _GrailsPackage_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
at _GrailsSettings_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets.leftShift(IncludeTargets.groovy:59)
at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets$leftShift.call(Unknown Source)
at _GrailsPlugins_groovy.run(_GrailsPlugins_groovy:33)
at _GrailsPlugins_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
at _GrailsCreateProject_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets.leftShift(IncludeTargets.groovy:59)
at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets$leftShift.call(Unknown Source)
at _GrailsCreateProject_groovy.run(_GrailsCreateProject_groovy:28)
at _GrailsCreateProject_groovy$run.call(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets.leftShift(IncludeTargets.groovy:59)
at org.codehaus.gant.IncludeTargets$leftShift.call(Unknown Source)
at CreateApp_.run(CreateApp_.groovy:25)
at CreateApp_$run.call(Unknown Source)
at gant.Gant.prepareTargets(Gant.groovy:607)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: _PluginDependencies_groovy$_run_closure1
... 32 more
| Error Error executing script CreateApp: _PluginDependencies_groovy$_run_closure1
```

Comment: Stacktrace is not helping. What is the environment setting, Grails version, etc?

Comment: Also do you have GRAILS_HOME & JAVA_HOME?

Comment: @Sérgio Michels. Yes I do have those settings, GRAILS_HOME=C:\grails-2.2.4
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_21

Comment: @dmahapatro  Grails version: 2.2.4

Answer (score 2):

I know this is quite old and for Linux, but this question was the 1st result when googling "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: _GrailsInit_groovy$_run_closure1_closure6".

On Linux, I fixed this with `source ~/.bashrc`
This is the file where you declare JAVA_HOME and GRAILS_HOME.

Maybe you need to reboot Windows in order to for these variables to take effect.

See [installing grails in linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8949631/installing-grails-in-linux)